# Python google-maps-services-python places autocomplete by types INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I just trying to get and autocomplete suggestions by the python package [google-map-services-python](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python). Everything works fine, except when I add the types parameter on my statement:

```
gmaps.places_autocomplete('new', session_token=my_token, language='de', types='cities')
```

I've checked the documentation and they said that the **types** param is an String parameter... but seems that I'm doing something wrong... It only works when I remove the types param and I need to only get suggestions by cities.

```
gmaps.places_autocomplete('new', session_token=my_token, language='de')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i just find the way to only filter results by cities, if anybody has the same problem as me, here is the answer.

```
gmaps.places_autocomplete('new', session_token=my_token,  types='(cities)')
```